# Issue with multiselect combobox control in Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I am creating a multiselect combobox in Windows 8 as shown in below image:

[image]

For this I have created custom control code for which is mentioned below:
The problem with below code is that

1. on selecting all the all items are not selected
2. Selected items are not displayed in textbox

How can I fix that?

XAML:

```
<UserControl
    x:Class="App5.MultiSelectComboBox"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:App5"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    d:DesignHeight="300"
    x:Name="thisUC"
    d:DesignWidth="400">

        <ComboBox
        x:Name="MultiSelectCombo"  
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
        ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
Width="400" Height="20" 
                           >
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <CheckBox Content="{Binding Title}" Foreground="Black"
                          IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=thisUC, Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"
                           Click="CheckBox_Click" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Grid >
                <ToggleButton 
                        x:Name="ToggleButton" 
                       Grid.Column="2" IsChecked="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"

                        ClickMode="Press" HorizontalContentAlignment="Left" >
                    <ToggleButton.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="18"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Border
                  x:Name="Border" 
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
                  CornerRadius="2"
                  Background="White"
                  BorderBrush="Black"
                  BorderThickness="1,1,1,1" />
                                <Border 
                    x:Name="BorderComp" 
                  Grid.Column="0"
                  CornerRadius="2" 
                  Margin="1" 
                 Background="White"
                  BorderBrush="Black"
                  BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" >
                                    <TextBlock Foreground="Black" Text="{TemplateBinding TextValue}" 
                            Padding="3" />
                                </Border>
                                <Path 
                  x:Name="Arrow"
                  Grid.Column="1"     
                  Fill="Black"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                  VerticalAlignment="Center"
                  Data="M 0 0 L 4 4 L 8 0 Z"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </ToggleButton.Template>
                </ToggleButton>
                <Popup 
                        Name="Popup"
                         IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsDropDownOpen}"
                        >
                    <Grid 
                        Name="DropDown"
                        MinWidth="{TemplateBinding ActualWidth}"
                        MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding MaxDropDownHeight}">
                        <Border x:Name="DropDownBorder"
                                   BorderThickness="1" Background="White"
                                    BorderBrush="Black"/>
                        <ScrollViewer Margin="4,6,4,6" DataContext="{Binding}">
                            <StackPanel  />
                        </ScrollViewer>
                    </Grid>
                </Popup>
            </Grid>
            <!--<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="HasItems" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="MinHeight" Value="95"/>
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger SourceName="Popup" Property="Popup.AllowsTransparency" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="CornerRadius" Value="4"/>
                        <Setter TargetName="DropDownBorder" Property="Margin" Value="0,2,0,0"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>-->
        </ControlTemplate>

    </ComboBox>
</UserControl>
```

C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Windows.Foundation;
using Windows.Foundation.Collections;
using Windows.UI.Xaml;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Input;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Media;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation;

// The User Control item template is documented at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=234236

namespace App5
{
    public sealed partial class MultiSelectComboBox : UserControl
    {
        private ObservableCollection<Node> _nodeList;
        public MultiSelectComboBox()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            _nodeList = new ObservableCollection<Node>();
        }

        #region Dependency Properties

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =
             DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", typeof(Dictionary<string, object>), typeof(MultiSelectComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(null,
        new PropertyChangedCallback(MultiSelectComboBox.OnItemsSourceChanged)));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedItemsProperty =
         DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedItems", typeof(Dictionary<string, object>), typeof(MultiSelectComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(null,
     new PropertyChangedCallback(MultiSelectComboBox.OnSelectedItemsChanged)));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty =
           DependencyProperty.Register("TextValue", typeof(string), typeof(MultiSelectComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty DefaultTextProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("DefaultText", typeof(string), typeof(MultiSelectComboBox), new PropertyMetadata(null));



        public Dictionary<string, object> ItemsSource
        {
            get { return (Dictionary<string, object>)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public Dictionary<string, object> SelectedItems
        {
            get { return (Dictionary<string, object>)GetValue(SelectedItemsProperty); }
            set
            {
                SetValue(SelectedItemsProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public string TextValue
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(TextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
        }

        public string DefaultText
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(DefaultTextProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DefaultTextProperty, value); }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Events
        private static void OnItemsSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MultiSelectComboBox control = (MultiSelectComboBox)d;
            control.DisplayInControl();
        }

        private static void OnSelectedItemsChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            MultiSelectComboBox control = (MultiSelectComboBox)d;
            control.SelectNodes();
            control.SetText();
        }

        private void CheckBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            CheckBox clickedBox = (CheckBox)sender;

            if (clickedBox.Content == "All")
            {
                if (clickedBox.IsChecked.Value)
                {
                    foreach (Node node in _nodeList)
                    {
                        node.IsSelected = true;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (Node node in _nodeList)
                    {
                        node.IsSelected = false;
                    }
                }

            }
            else
            {
                int _selectedCount = 0;
                foreach (Node s in _nodeList)
                {
                    if (s.IsSelected && s.Title != "All")
                        _selectedCount++;
                }
                if (_selectedCount == _nodeList.Count - 1)
                    _nodeList.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Title == "All").IsSelected = true;
                else
                    _nodeList.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Title == "All").IsSelected = false;
            }
            SetSelectedItems();
            SetText();

        }
        #endregion


        #region Methods
        private void SelectNodes()
        {
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> keyValue in SelectedItems)
            {
                Node node = _nodeList.FirstOrDefault(i => i.Title == keyValue.Key);
                if (node != null)
                    node.IsSelected = true;
            }
        }

        private void SetSelectedItems()
        {
            if (SelectedItems == null)
                SelectedItems = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            SelectedItems.Clear();
            foreach (Node node in _nodeList)
            {
                if (node.IsSelected && node.Title != "All")
                {
                    if (this.ItemsSource.Count > 0)

                        SelectedItems.Add(node.Title, this.ItemsSource[node.Title]);
                }
            }
        }

        private void DisplayInControl()
        {
            _nodeList.Clear();
            if (this.ItemsSource.Count > 0)
                _nodeList.Add(new Node("All"));
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> keyValue in this.ItemsSource)
            {
                Node node = new Node(keyValue.Key);
                _nodeList.Add(node);
            }

            MultiSelectCombo.ItemsSource = _nodeList;
        }

        private void SetText()
        {
            if (this.SelectedItems != null)
            {
                StringBuilder displayText = new StringBuilder();
                foreach (Node s in _nodeList)
                {
                    if (s.IsSelected == true && s.Title == "All")
                    {
                        displayText = new StringBuilder();
                        displayText.Append("All");
                        break;
                    }
                    else if (s.IsSelected == true && s.Title != "All")
                    {
                        displayText.Append(s.Title);
                        displayText.Append(',');
                    }
                }
                this.TextValue = displayText.ToString().TrimEnd(new char[] { ',' });
            }
            // set DefaultText if nothing else selected
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.TextValue))
            {
                this.TextValue = this.DefaultText;
            }
        }


        #endregion
    }

    public class Node : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        private string _title;
        private bool _isSelected;
        #region ctor
        public Node(string title)
        {
            Title = title;
        }
        #endregion

        #region Properties
        public string Title
        {
            get
            {
                return _title;
            }
            set
            {
                _title = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Title");
            }
        }
        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get
            {
                return _isSelected;
            }
            set
            {
                _isSelected = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsSelected");
            }
        }
        #endregion

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I understand what you want. Overall, I would recommend a slightly different approach. I would recommend, for one, that you not use a `ComboBox` to accomplish this - an `ItemsControl` will accomplish what you want with less work and overhead. Using a `Popup` like you are is great, but let me show you a slightly simplified way that (this is the best part) works the way you are asking in your question.

[image]

Here's your XAML:

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel/>
    </Grid.DataContext>
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBox Width="200" FontSize="24" Text="{Binding Header, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                 IsReadOnly="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxHeight="200" />
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" MaxHeight="200" Width="200" Background="White">
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <CheckBox Content="{Binding Text}" 
                          FontSize="24" 
                          Foreground="Black"
                          IsChecked="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                          IsThreeState="False" />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Here's your code-behind:

```
public class Item : BindableBase
{
    public string Text { get; set; }

    bool _IsChecked = default(bool);
    public bool IsChecked { get { return _IsChecked; } set { SetProperty(ref _IsChecked, value); } }
}

public class ViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public ViewModel()
    {
        _Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>(Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
            .Select(x => new Item()
            {
                Text = string.Format("Item {0}", x),
                IsChecked = (x < 4) ? true : false,
            }));
        foreach (var item in this.Items)
            item.PropertyChanged += (s, e) => base.RaisePropertyChanged("Header");
    }

    public string Header
    {
        get
        {
            var array = this.Items
                .Where(x => x.IsChecked)
                .Select(x => x.Text).ToArray();
            if (!array.Any())
                return "None";
            return string.Join("; ", array);
        }
    }

    ObservableCollection<Item> _Items;
    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get { return _Items; } }
}

public abstract class BindableBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected void SetProperty<T>(ref T storage, T value, 
        [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
    {
        if (!object.Equals(storage, value))
        {
            storage = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged([System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] String propertyName = null)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Thnks Its a great approach

Comment: You're great, Jerry :)

Answer (score 0):

Your all code is correct, except one thing, that's data binding of `CheckBox` in `ComboBox`'s `DataTemplate`. You don't need to use `ElementName=thisUC`

**Incorrect**

```xml
<CheckBox Content="{Binding Title}" Foreground="Black" 
    IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=thisUC, Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Click="CheckBox_Click" />
```

**Correct**

```xml
<CheckBox Content="{Binding Title}" Foreground="Black" Click="CheckBox_Click"
    IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. But still I am not able to see the selected items coma separated as shown in image. on selecting items nothing is displayed

Comment: Oh you want that, then you should use listbox and textbox. The autocompletebox control will help you.

Comment: I want it to be like multi select dropdown hence I created this user control. But the only issue is that i am not able to figure out that why the TextValue poperty created in this User control.cs file is not getting binded to XAML. If it does then this is working. Can you please check that why in SetText() method the value of TextValue property is not getting binded to the UI properly

Comment: Your XAML seems incorrect, the textbox is not getting visibility due to combo box.

Comment: So pls could you suggest how can i fix this.